# How to lock a branch using TFS API in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-sdk

Is it possible to lock a branch using TFS API in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you already know how to connect to TFS and get a specific workspace.

With that said, you would use Workspace.PendEdit for this.

[Workspace.PendEdit Method (String[], RecursionType, String, LockLevel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139377%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

The enum LockLevel is defined here:

[LockLevel Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.locklevel.aspx)

This acts the same as the UI if you were to right-click inside of TFS on the branch itself and perform the lock.

Comment: But with the UI I am able to lock a folder and also affecting the children without getting it local. From the API I have to get it first and then apply a recursive lock.
Found it. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679141/how-to-lock-a-branch-using-tfs-api-in-tfs-2010/7123781#7123781)

Answer (score 1):

[Workspace.SetLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.setlock%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)